# Merge datasets comparing columns of different sizes

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, dataset, unique

I need to merge datasets that have been collected in different years ( 2020, 2016, 2014, 2012). I don't want to merge them horizzontally, but vertically.. let's say that I want to add them. The variables are the same. The problem is that they should be referred to different people, but same identification codes can have been used in the questionairres

here a sample of the datasets

```
 nquest nord sex anasc ireg eta staciv studio  apqual asnonoc nace nesplav exlav etalav 
1    173    1   1  1948   18  72      3      5     15       2   19       1    NA     25      
2   2886    1   1  1949   13  71      1      5     15       2   16       1    NA     26      
3   2886    2   2  1952   13  68      1      6     15       2   17       1    NA     20      
4   5416    1   2  1958    8  62      3      3     15       1   19       3     1     16      
5   7886    1   1  1950    9  70      1      5     15       2   11       1    NA     22      
6  20297    1   1  1960    5  60      1      3     15       1   19       3     1     14
```

Actually, there isn't a unique identification code for each individual but a combination of two. The variable `nquest` is the code for the family, while `nord` is the code to indicate the component. For instance, `nquest = 2886` is the family code, while `nord = 1` is the husband and `nord = 2` is the wife.

I need to merge these 4 datasets. I have thought that the first thing is to check if same code has been used and in that case change it.

I've tried

```
ifelse(data2020$nquest == data2016$nquest, 'Problem', 'dont worry')
```

But R replies

```
Warning message:
In data2020$nquest == data2016$nquest :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The reason is that they have a different size ( 2020 -> n° 3400 , 2016 -> n° 4114 , 2014 -> n° 4552 , 2012 -> n° 4396)

As consequence, I've thought that I can assign a unique identification code by myself and then merge them

```
data2020 <- data2020 %>%
  group_by(nquest, nord) %>%
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id())

data2016 <- data2016 %>%
  group_by(nquest, nord) %>%
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id())
```

and then

```
big_data <- rbind(data2020, data2016)
```

Am I doing it in the right way? I have to put the final dataset into a regression, hence it is important to me that each observation is referred clearly to a specific individual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `lst` to obtain a named list and then `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

lst(data2014,
    data2016,
    data2020) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "year")
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 18 × 15
   year     nquest  nord   sex anasc  ireg   eta staciv studio apqual asnonoc  nace nesplav exlav etalav
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 data2014    173     1     1  1948    18    72      3      5     15       2    19       1    NA     25
 2 data2014   2886     1     1  1949    13    71      1      5     15       2    16       1    NA     26
 3 data2014   2886     2     2  1952    13    68      1      6     15       2    17       1    NA     20
 4 data2014   5416     1     2  1958     8    62      3      3     15       1    19       3     1     16
 5 data2014   7886     1     1  1950     9    70      1      5     15       2    11       1    NA     22
 6 data2014  20297     1     1  1960     5    60      1      3     15       1    19       3     1     14
 7 data2016    173     1     1  1948    18    72      3      5     15       2    19       1    NA     25
 8 data2016   2886     1     1  1949    13    71      1      5     15       2    16       1    NA     26
 9 data2016   2886     2     2  1952    13    68      1      6     15       2    17       1    NA     20
10 data2016   5416     1     2  1958     8    62      3      3     15       1    19       3     1     16
11 data2016   7886     1     1  1950     9    70      1      5     15       2    11       1    NA     22
12 data2016  20297     1     1  1960     5    60      1      3     15       1    19       3     1     14
13 data2020    173     1     1  1948    18    72      3      5     15       2    19       1    NA     25
14 data2020   2886     1     1  1949    13    71      1      5     15       2    16       1    NA     26
15 data2020   2886     2     2  1952    13    68      1      6     15       2    17       1    NA     20
16 data2020   5416     1     2  1958     8    62      3      3     15       1    19       3     1     16
17 data2020   7886     1     1  1950     9    70      1      5     15       2    11       1    NA     22
18 data2020  20297     1     1  1960     5    60      1      3     15       1    19       3     1     14
```

**Data:**

```r
library(readr)

data2014 <- read_table("nquest nord sex anasc ireg eta staciv studio  apqual asnonoc nace nesplav exlav etalav
173    1   1  1948   18  72      3      5     15       2   19       1    NA     25      
2886    1   1  1949   13  71      1      5     15       2   16       1    NA     26      
2886    2   2  1952   13  68      1      6     15       2   17       1    NA     20      
5416    1   2  1958    8  62      3      3     15       1   19       3     1     16      
7886    1   1  1950    9  70      1      5     15       2   11       1    NA     22      
20297    1   1  1960    5  60      1      3     15       1   19       3     1     14")

data2016 <- read_table("nquest nord sex anasc ireg eta staciv studio  apqual asnonoc nace nesplav exlav etalav
173    1   1  1948   18  72      3      5     15       2   19       1    NA     25      
2886    1   1  1949   13  71      1      5     15       2   16       1    NA     26      
2886    2   2  1952   13  68      1      6     15       2   17       1    NA     20      
5416    1   2  1958    8  62      3      3     15       1   19       3     1     16      
7886    1   1  1950    9  70      1      5     15       2   11       1    NA     22      
20297    1   1  1960    5  60      1      3     15       1   19       3     1     14")

data2020 <- read_table("nquest nord sex anasc ireg eta staciv studio  apqual asnonoc nace nesplav exlav etalav
173    1   1  1948   18  72      3      5     15       2   19       1    NA     25      
2886    1   1  1949   13  71      1      5     15       2   16       1    NA     26      
2886    2   2  1952   13  68      1      6     15       2   17       1    NA     20      
5416    1   2  1958    8  62      3      3     15       1   19       3     1     16      
7886    1   1  1950    9  70      1      5     15       2   11       1    NA     22      
20297    1   1  1960    5  60      1      3     15       1   19       3     1     14")
```